# squareup how to use test nonces to save card on file that will be declined

Tags: square-connect, square

In the docs [here](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/testing/test-values#generating-error-states) I can see that there are test nonces.
I want to create cards on file that will be declined when charging payments.
I've tried all these nonces and none seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Both requests below fail.

```
   squareClient.customersApi.createCustomerCard(
            createCustomer,
            CreateCustomerCardRequest.Builder("cnon:card-nonce-declined").build()
        )
   squareClient.customersApi.createCustomerCard(
            createCustomer,
            CreateCustomerCardRequest.Builder("ccof:customer-card-id-declined").build()
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to save a card on file that will later fail in the sandbox environment, since `CreateCustomerCard`, by design, authorizes the card upon creation. So if the card is going to fail, it won't be able to save and fail later.

Comment: What about if they save it and then cancel it?